# How to improve performance saving spark streaming output

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have written a spark streaming project that logs the output to a file using saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile forEachRDD.  But this operation is extremely slow.If I comment saving output to a file I can process 1000 events per min with this saving output to a file I can only process 250 events per minute.
My code is very simple just these two lines.

```
if (rdd !=null && !rdd.isEmpty() && !rdd.partitions().isEmpty()) {
    String file =3D getOutputLocation(contextVal.getString(FEATURE_SCORE_OU=
TPUT_LOCATION));
    rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(file, Text.class, Text.class, outputFormatCl=
ass);
}
```

Is there any way I can improve the performance.  Should I collect the data in memory or in HBase or somewhere then perform logging into HDFS once after we have sufficient data?  If I have a huge data and I want to log output to HDFS then what is the recommendation?  If I log eachRDD of the DStream then it is extremely slow.  Should I collect data for each partition then log.  Unable to find the recommended way of logging data to HDFS efficiently while doing stream processing.

Comment: I don't think you can save time here simply by caching RDD. Serialization and Deserialization along with DB queries are very costly operations. This is one reason Spark uses light weight Kryo serialization to move objects quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your response Amit.  I had already configured Kryo as default serialization.  But here I am just saving string to HDFS for each dstream which is very expensive for each output write.

Comment: why are you saving multiple times, I don't see any benefit in saving rdds to hdfs each time you process one of them. What you are actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: We are getting data from Kafka stream we are doing some processing on that data and logging the output in HDFS.

Comment: Try doing saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile on the dStream rather than rdd. Second thing I will say read about Design Patterns for using foreachRDD http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd